# What is difference between github main and master branch?

Tags: git, push, git-branch

I changed default branch from `main` to `master` and deleted main and now when I am trying to push using command

```
git push -u origin master
```

I am getting error.
I tried `git push -f origin master` and it works don't know why?

Comment: Don't just say "getting error". Include the *exact command* (cut and paste it) and the *exact error text* (again, cut and paste it, put the whole thing in a code quote block). See [ask].

Comment: @torek if OP posted the error then this would be a dup. Hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it :

```
git pull --rebase origin main
git push -u origin main
```

It will work and your files will be pushed into main repository.